# MySQL DateTime join two large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables and want to do a join between them and sum up some columns. The join criteria should be that table A's time is within 1 and 5 mins of table B's time.

So B.time <= A.time <= B.time + (1|5) minutes

Here is the code and I have indexes (btree) on both datetime columns. But it appears to run SUPER SLOW. Anything I can do differently?

```
SELECT
    a.Name,
    SUM(b.UnitsSold),
    SUM(b.Revenue),
    SUM(c.UnitsSold),
    SUM(c.Revenue)
FROM cars a
INNER JOIN sales b
ON
    b.Datet <= a.Datet
    and a.Datet <= DATE_ADD(b.Datet, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
INNER JOIN sales c
ON
    c.Datet <= a.Datet
    and a.Datet <= DATE_ADD(c.Datet, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
GROUP BY
    a.name
```

Comment: Inequality queries are really slow.  I would suggest that you ask a question with sample data, desired results, and a more complete explanation of the logic you want.

Comment: I agree with @Gordon Linoff that it would be a lot easier to help you if you provided sample data and a sample of the desired output. That being said, your code looks plenty legit, but the server is having to do 8 calculations for each record (as well as two inner joins). So, especially if we're talking about thousands of records, it's not surprising it is running slowly. Can you limit the number of included records with a simple WHERE clause (e.g, WHERE date >= "2018-01-01")? That would help because the query engine can exclude the appropriate records before other calculations are made.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, without sample data, desired results and explanation of the logic behind what you need, it's difficult to help, but here's a potential solution you could try:

Create two new columns in your sales table (Datet_b and Datet_c) and on insert/update, run the DATE_ADD function to populate them.

Add indexes for those two columns and then run the query above without the DATE_ADD function in there.

Run the query and the performance should be a little better